# SQL Regex Split Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

I am working on an application which is used to scrape data from an excel spreadsheet and store it into a database. The data is not normalized in excel so the scrape needs to be very flexible. I have recently changed the implementation to be somewhat more generic where before

I was storing the `ExcelCellLocation` and now have broken it up into `ExcelColumn`, `ExcelRowStart`, and `ExcelRowEnd`.

I am looking for a way to take all of the rows in that table and split up the `ExcelCellLocation` into the new implementation.

For example:

```
ExcelCellLocation
F5
AB23
```

Becomes

```
ExcelColumn | ExcelRowStart | ExcelRowEnd
F           | 5             | 5
AB          | 23            | 23
```

The reason for the change is that I am now scraping another spreadsheet in the workbook and the implementation needed to be changed in order to better suit the new spreadsheet while still working for the spreadsheet currently being scraped. The new mappings will look more like this:

```
ExcelColumn | ExcelRowStart | ExcelRowEnd
BC          | 10            | 150
BC          | 160           | 300
```

Is there a way to do this with a SQL script that will iterate through each record and make the apropriate changes?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You've included the regex tag, and I can easily imagine a regular expression to transform the `F5` and `AB23` into `F` & `5` or `AB` & `23` respectively, but I am not sure if you've included enough information about the data structure to get an answer - mostly because I'm not sure what your question is!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-- Sample data
;with T(ExcelCellLocation) as
(
  select 'F5' union all
  select 'AB23'  
)

-- Query
select  
       left(ExcelCellLocation, patindex('%[0-9]%', ExcelCellLocation)-1) as ExcelColumn,
       stuff(ExcelCellLocation, 1, patindex('%[0-9]%', ExcelCellLocation)-1, '') as RowStart
from T
```

Result:

```
ExcelColumn RowStart
----------- -----------
F           5
AB          23
```

Comment: I think this answer clarifies a few of my questions concerning my comment on the question itself :D

Comment: @MikaelEriksson Thanks this works great in the query. how would I use this query to commit it back to the database instead of just return it in a query?